# flask send_file not working with tar.gz files

Tags: python, flask, tar, gzip, sendfile

I have a `my_folder.tar.gz` archive with a structure

```
my_folder.tar.gz:
    my_folder/
        file1
        file2
```

And I construct a basic flask endpoint, say:

```
@blueprint.route('/download')
def download():
    return send_file('/path/to/my_folder.tar.gz',
                     as_attachment=True,
                     attachment_filename='my_name.tar.gz')
```

And when I run it the first time everything runs smoothly and the browser downloads the proper archive. The thing is when I run it the second time, inside the archive there's a file `my-name.tar-1` and not the folder I was hoping to send. I try another time, the filename `my-name.tar-2` etc etc.

It turns out that when I change the `attachment_filename` parameter to a new value, the download works again but also only once. The same situation happens with the `send_from_directory()` function.

That's a very bizarre behaviour. Does anybody have an idea what might be happening?

Comment: It sounds like your client is renaming the file. A lot of browsers do this when there is a name conflict. What happens if you delete the downloaded file before you download it a second time?

Comment: Hmmmm, actually when I download it on the hard drive everything is fine. The problem occurs only when I click `Open with` and not `Save file` in the browser dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use,

```
return send_file('/path/to/my_folder.tar.gz',as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='my_name.tar.gz, cache_timeout=0')
```